# Unix find with exec + and extra variables

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting, sh

I have a need for recursively looking through a directory and pass all files with a certain extension to a script. In addition it also takes some optional command lines arguments from the user. To put it all together, I did this

```
usage="blah"
while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
  case $1 in
    -arg1 )  shift
             arg1=$1
             ;;
    -arg2 )  shift
             arg2=$1
             ;;
    * )      echo $usage
             exit 1
  esac
  shift
done

find . -name "*.ext" -exec bash -c 'command "$0" arg1="${arg1:-default}" arg2=${arg2:-default}' "{}" \+
```

However this runs the 'command' command and only passes one file in. How do I get to send the list of files as an argument as well as keep the command line arguments?

EDIT: The command should run only once for the list of matched files.

Comment: BTW, quoting the `{}` in `find ... -exec ... {} +` is only needed for zsh, and the `+` doesn't need to be quoted at all.

Comment: Does using `"$@"` and `- {}` do what you want? Does argument order between the `find`-provided arguments and `arg1`/`arg2` matter?

Comment: ...as another aside, `command` is an actual shell builtin, so when you use it, folks have to figure out from context whether you actually mean `command` or if it's a placeholder. Consider something like `mycommand` or `yourcommand` in examples instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `bash -c` here at all!

```
find . -name '*.ext' \
  -exec yourcommand arg1="${arg1:-default}" arg2="${arg2:-default}" {} +
```

See edit history for a discussion of exactly how the old version was broken and how to do more targeted fixes for cases when you really do need a shell.

Comment: Forgot to mention one thing - I want to supply all files and run the command just once. Not run it once per file.

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. If the list is too long that actually might not be possible -- like `xargs` (or any other program on UNIX), `find -exec ... {} +` can't put more entries on a command line that will fit in ARG_MAX. However, that makes your question much easier. :)

Comment: the `@$` tip is very handy. Thanks!